# make sure that transform.translate doesn't get out of container

Tags: flutter, dart

is there a way to make sure that Transform.translate doesn't go outside of the container?
even if the values logically put it outside?
so if the container is at the center of the screen and something is moved at -200 of that container I want it to be only show the part that's inside the container
SizedBox and ConstrainedBox don't seem to help

my current code is:

```dart
return ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(Size(400, 400)),
    child: Container(
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Stack(
            children: [
                AnimatedBuilder(
                    animation: animationController,
                    child: // ...,
                    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                        return Transform.translate(
                            offset: Offset(positionLeft, positionRight),
                            child: child
                        );
                    },
                ),
                //...
            ]
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well apparently I found a solution, wrapping the container with ClipRect instead of ContrainedBox did it